# can we use xsl:for-each closing tag without using xsl:for-each opening tag in xsl file?

Tags: xslt

I am start learning xsl.Today when I read a code , I saw tag used without using  open tag.I saw for loop is used in scriplet. and then followed by Is it possible to use?Please answer me with example.Thanks.

This is the following code line:

```
<% for (int l_i = 0; l_i < 10; l_i++) { %>
                        some code   
                        <% } %>
                        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: You can't have a closing tag in XSLT without an opening tag, because XSLT has to be well-formed XML. The code snippet you have shown looks like it might have come from ASP.Net, or some other language. It is code that is generating an XSLT file, not actually running the XSLT file. It's probably not a good place to start if you are learning XSLT.

Comment: Look around in your source. Maybe opening _xsl:for-each_ tag is somewhere earlier.